# Asyncio attribute error, pyinstaller bundle

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

Application works, but when I'm trying to run it as executable I receive such error:

```py
File "venv\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\tcp_helpers.py", line 20, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'asyncio' has no attribute 'Transport'
[8748] Failed to execute script restapi
```

Why does it happen?

Comment: Do you have file named `asyncio.py` somewhere in your project files? If so, you should rename it to avoid conflict with `asyncio` module.

Comment: Problem was in hidden imports,  I used absolute path to uvicorn. I thought it was again Pyinstaller related problem, because it can't hook some modules without pointing path to them.